# Unable to export shapefile for each date using pgsql2shp on Windows 10

Tags: windows, postgresql, batch-file, cmd, postgis

I have a table in my PostgreSQL 11 database, same linestring geometry but different attributes (hourly data) for each date. I am trying to export the attributes for each date into a separate shapefile. I am on Windows 10 (x64) PC and trying to use the `pgsql2shp` utility.

The following line of code works (assume I want first 50 dates so `1..50`), but it outputs the whole table (`1..50.shp`) instead of separate tables for each date:

```
for %i in (1..50) ; do pgsql2shp -f %i.shp -h localhost -p my_port -u postgres -P my_code postgres public.my_table '"select * from my_table where date = $i"'; done
```

How can I fix the above line to export shapefiles for each date?

Comment: Are you on the Windows command line?  Then your `for` syntax is wrong. See `for /?`

Comment: Yes, I am on windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /L %i in (1,1,50) do pgsql2shp -f %i.shp -h localhost -p my_port -u postgres -P my_code postgres public.my_table '"select * from my_table where date = %i"'
```

Notes :

The `for /L` syntax as mentioned by Stephan.

The semicolon is seen as a separator, same as <kbd>Space</kbd>

The `$i` in the SQL statement should be `%i` to substitute `%i`'s value.

The `; done` I don't know about - it may be required.

If this is executed as a line in a batch file, each `%i` needs to be `%%i`. That might save a whole lot of error-prone re-typing.

Comment: Hi Magoo, thank you very much for the help! I am testing `for /L in (1,1,5)` for first five dates and in the output I get all the rows in each shapefile, not the ones specific for each date. So, probably, for loop range should be date? or SQL within the quotes need improvement?

Comment: The `date` column in the postgres table is like, `2016-01-01, 2016-01-01, 2016-01-01..., 2016-01-02` and so on..

Comment: (from the syntax in the question, I guess `; done` is supposed to close the loop - not needed with this one-line loop in batch).